# Swift Programmatic Constraint not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to create a uiview that has a segment control inside. I want to be able to add this uiview to my viewcontroller's view. the segment control should be right on top of my tableview. but everytime i setup the constraints i keep getting this error
"Thread 1: Exception: "Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x282ee24c0 "UIView:0x119d3a610.bottom"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x282ee2500 "UITableView:0x11a014a00.top"> because they have no common ancestor.  Does the constraint or its anchors reference items in different view hierarchies?  That's illegal."" I tried working around by adding the subview first and what not but it's not working. here's my code if anyone can help me.

```
    func configureTableView(){
    setupSegmentControl()
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    
    setTableViewDelegates()
    tableView.rowHeight = 50
    tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    self.tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: self.view.topAnchor, multiplier: 20).isActive = true
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CustomCellNSB2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCellNSB2")
}
func setTableViewDelegates(){
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
func setupSegmentControl(){

    var headerView = UIView()
    var importanceSegmentControl = CustomSegmentControl()
    headerView.addSubview(importanceSegmentControl)

    self.view.addSubview(headerView)



    importanceSegmentControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(indexChanged(control:)),for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)


    headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    headerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    headerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    headerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    headerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    
    importanceSegmentControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    importanceSegmentControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    importanceSegmentControl.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    importanceSegmentControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    importanceSegmentControl.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: headerView.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tableView` and `importanceSegmentControl` doesn't have any common ancestor at the time of adding the constraint to the `importanceSegmentControl`. So to fix the issue just switch the order of execution:

```
func configureTableView(){
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    setupSegmentControl()
    //...
}
```